# Flutter error when running for release. IN debug works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I receive an error when ever I try to run the Release version of my app and the app sticks on the launch screen. I never have an error with the debug version, which has been well tested.

I haven't been able to find any information on this error message here at Stackoverflow or in the git forums. So hoping someone can help me on this one, as I'm completely stuck!
Here is the error message from Xcode:

> 2019-10-30 11:00:28.072780+0800 Runner[1311:409348] Metal API Validation Enabled
>   ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/exceptions.cc: 425: error: unreachable code

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing to a newer version of Dart, which contained a fix for this issue.
I did this by switching my channel to run on Master Channel (from Beta channel).
Here's is some instructions that I used, I hope it can be of help to anyone else experiencing this issue:

[Flutter Channels - Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels)